# is WGET correct for this cron job?

Tags: cron

I'm using Bluehost which gives the option to set up a cron job with the command, and then they give you settings options for setting the timing the job should run. I think I have these commands set up properly, but I'm not sure. The file they're getting is are .xml files. And I'm using them with WP All Import which gave me everything to use in the command ( I replaced the actual username with username - but I know that the client's username would go there ).

```
wget -q -O /dev/null "/home/username/public_html/wp-cron.php?import_key=tG.IEkYZ&import_id=4&action=trigger"

wget -q -O /dev/null "/home/username/public_html/wp-cron.php?import_key=tG.IEkYZ&import_id=4&action=processing"

wget -q -O /dev/null "/home/username/public_html/wp-cron.php?import_key=tG.IEkYZ&import_id=5&action=trigger"

wget -q -O /dev/null "/home/username/public_html/wp-cron.php?import_key=tG.IEkYZ&import_id=5&action=processing"
```

Comment: A friend said that wget was for when the file is on a remote server... and since this one is one their own server, it's wrong. Here's what he recommended.

`/path/to/php /home/username/public_html/wp-cron.php?import_key=tG.IEkYZ&import_id=5&action=processing`

I've changed it and will see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

wget was fine. The client's theme had a coming soon feature that was keeping the cron from processing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @tfrommen This was a self answer ;)

Comment: @angiemeeker Glad you solved this - feel free to mark this answer as accepted, you can do that with your own answers too :)